# How to get data for specified user from front end(React js) to back end(Node js, MySQL)

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs

I want to get the the data for specified user from MySQL, there isn't any error, but nothing display
This is because in the index.js in the server, the id undefined, how can i take the id from the front end!
What is the error in my code?

This is in the front end (React js)

```
function EditCourse() {

    const [CourseID, setCourseID] = useState(0);
    const [Name, setName] = useState("");
    const [Description, setDescription] = useState("");
    const [TeacherSSN, setTeacherSSN] = useState(0);

    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const { id } = useParams();

 useEffect(() => {
            debugger;
            Axios.get(`http://localhost:3003/fetchdata/${id}`, {
                CourseID: CourseID,
                Name: Name,
                Description: Description,
                TeacherSSN: TeacherSSN,
            }).then(result => setData(result.data));
            console.log("success")
            debugger;
        }, [id]);
return(
       <div>
{data.map(item => {
    return (
                <div key={item.Id}>

                    <h2>
                        رقم الدورة :
                    </h2>
                    <br />
                    <input type="text" value={item.CourseID}/>
                    <h2>
                        اسم الدورة :
                    </h2>
                    <br />
                    <input type="text" value={item.Name}/>
                    <br />
                    <h2>
                        رقم هوية مدرب الدورة :
                    </h2>
                    <br />
                    <input type="text" value={item.TeacherSSN}/>
                    <br />
                    <p> تفاصيل الدورة :</p>
                    <br />
                    <TextField
                        label={item.Description}
                        color="secondary"
                        variant="outlined"
                        multiline/>
</div>
) }) }
</div>
) }
```

And this is the index.js in the server

```
app.get(`/fetchdata/:id`,(req, res) => {
  const id = req.body.id;
  console.log(id);
  db.query(`SELECT CourseID, TeacherSSN, Name, Description FROM course WHERE CourseID=${id}`, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
    } else {
      res.send(result)
    }
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the `id` through URL params, while you are trying to get the `id` from the request body.

Replace

```js
const id = req.body.id;
```

To

```js
const id = req.params.id;
```

Comment: I add to all text on change, but i can't change the value in the texts, i can't write.

Comment: How can i write in the texts and change the value 